# How to get access token Using Service Account

Tags: java, android, google-api, in-app-purchase

I want to get access token using service account but the problem is where to put the `json` file ?  How to link it . In doc section there is no proper guidelines . Do i need a `asynctask` ?

Here is the code :

```
    HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId("")
        .setServiceAccountScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher")
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(keyFile) // where to put the json file?
        .build();
      AccessToken accessToken = credentials.refreshAccessToken();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Steps** for the getting access token from Service account.

```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
          override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
                authExplicit()
            }
             fun authExplicit() {
                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
                        try {
                            val credentials =
                                GoogleCredentials.fromStream(resources.assets.open("studentsamplechatbot-xvgloa.json"))
                                    .createScoped(Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dialogflow"))
                            credentials.refreshIfExpired()
                            val accessToken = credentials.accessToken
                            Log.e("log_data", "Token :" + accessToken.tokenValue)
                            if (accessToken.tokenValue.isNotEmpty()) {
                                Log.e(
                                    "log_data",
                                    "Got it --> authenticationType :" + credentials.authenticationType
                                )
                                AuthToken = "Bearer " + accessToken.tokenValue
                            } else {
                                Log.e("log_data", "No token")
                                AuthToken = ""
                            }
                            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                                initViews()
                            }
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Log.e("log_data", e.toString())
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

You can download from Google Cloud Platform

1. **Google Cloud Platform** -> **Select your Project** -> **IAM & Admin** ->  **Service accounts** -> **Create Service Account**
2. Create a Service Account will open one page there are several details that add details and create it.
3. After Creating a Service account, you can find a created service account on the list.
4. From the right side, there is actions column is there with three dots with each. from that, there is one option **create key**. When you click on that it will open one dialog with two options **JSON** and **P12**. When you select **JSON** and click on create, it will download the JSON file of your service account.
5. You can use this JSON file for your Android project and place it into an `assets` folder.
   **Your Project** -> **app** -> **src** -> **main** -> **assets**
6. You can use the above function for getting access token.